# How should I pass form data to my new action as a way to prepare the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Invoices and in the invoices index I have a "create new invoice" button. That brings up a form where they select which client the invoice is for. However, I'm not sure how to pass this to the invoices#new action to prepare the data before the next page loads. How do I go about doing that?

EDIT:

The form before the invoices#new page basically just tells the invoice which client it is for. Then i'll have the client's address that can be automatically populated in the invoice new page

Comment: Some code would be helpful. What kind of info are you passing, how much info and what for? For example, does the info chosen change the type of form they later see, or only auto-complete some input fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller for the select client action do the following (I'll just call it `select_client`):

```
def select_client
  @clients = Client.all
end
```

On your first form do something like:

```
<%= form_tag(new_invoice_path, method: :get %>
# the above can use GET or you could leave it out if you wanted
  <%= select_tag "client", options_from_collection_for_select(@clients, "id", "name") %>
  # button etc.
<% end %>
```

Then in `invoices#new`

```
def new
  # after completing the previous form the invoices#new URL should have the
  # client ID attached to it, http://localhost:3000/invoices/new?client=3
  @client = Client.find(params[:client])
  # the next line should auto-populate your form in invoices/new.html.erb
  @invoice = Invoice.new(address: @client.address, name: @client.name)
end
```